# "no rules expected the token" when writing a `let` statement in a macro

Tags: rust, let

When I try to compile this code using `rustc main.rs`:

```
macro_rules! getPI {
    let pi = 3.141592;
    println!("Pi is roughly 3.142 \n {0}", pi);
}

fn main() {
    print!(getPI);
}
```

it gives me an error:

```
error: no rules expected the token `pi`
 --> src/main.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     let pi = 3.141592;
  |         ^^
```

I'm very new to programing, I hope someone has a solution.

Comment: Why do you want this to be a macro?

Comment: @sepp2k Testing around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are "very new to programing", then you should start at the beginning; macros are *not* the beginning. Go back and re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*, second edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/), even though it's targeted at people who already understand another programming language.

You can then read [the chapter from the first edition about macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/macros.html). This will show you the proper syntax for macros. Macros have a number of arms, like a `match` statement:

```
macro_rules! getPI {
    () => {
        let pi = 3.141592;
        println!("Pi is roughly 3.142 \n {0}", pi);
    }
}

fn main() {
    getPI!();
}
```

I also don't know why you'd try to `print!` the return value of your macro, so I removed that. You must also call the macro using an exclamation mark (`!`).